# new to MS SQL, have to find difference in hours of first and second row of same column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, gaps-and-islands

For eg. comparing first row and second row of invoice_status_change_datetime, until it goes to different status, have to capture the duration in hrs.

```
**AP_WORK_ID    INVOICE_STATUS  INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME   LAST_UPDATED_USER**
  1060565       Assigned        **2020-01-27 07:17:57.837**          xxxxxx
  1060565       Assigned        **2020-01-27 10:17:57.837**          yyyyyy
  1060565       In Progress       2020-01-29 01:08:56.943            xxxxxx
  1060565       Rejected          2020-01-28 07:17:57.837            xxxxxx
  1060565       Hold              2020-01-28 10:17:57.837            yyyyyy
  1060565       Closed            2020-01-29 01:08:56.943            xxxxxx
```

But the Result should be like below, because i want to merge this result with other join conditions

```
**AP_WORK_ID    Assigned_hrs  In Progress_hrs  Query_Resolved_hrs Rejected_hrs hold_hrs closed_hrs**
  1060565       24            3 hrs            null               10hrs        5hrs     null
```

I tried the code using lead(), i get the output also in hrs, but i dont know how to transform in the above format:

```
SELECT isc.INVOICE_STATUS,
    isc.INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME,
    DATEDIFF(HH, isc.INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME, LEAD(isc.INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME) OVER(
    ORDER BY isc.INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME)) AS status_change_Hours       
FROM INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE ISC
where isc.AP_WORK_ID = 1060565
GROUP BY isc.INVOICE_STATUS, isc.INVOICE_STATUS_CHANGE_DATETIME
```

I understand this is bit complex, Could anyone who is mastered in SQL know how to achieve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am thinking `lead()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select
    ap_work_id,
    sum(case when invoice_status = 'Assigned'    
        then datediff(hour, change_dt, next_change_dt) end) assigned_hrs,
    sum(case when invoice_status = 'In Progress' 
        then datediff(hour, change_dt, next_change_dt) end) in_progress_hrs,
    sum(case when invoice_status = 'Rejected'
        then datediff(hour, change_dt, next_change_dt) end) rejected_hrs,
    sum(case when invoice_status = 'Hold' 
        then datediff(hour, change_dt, next_change_dt) end) hold_hrs,
    sum(case when invoice_status = 'Closed' 
        then datediff(hour, change_dt, next_change_dt) end) closed_hrs
from (
    select 
        ap_work_id,
        invoice_status,
        invoice_status_change_datetime change_dt,
        lead(invoice_status_change_datetime) 
            over(partition by ap_work_id order by invoice_status_change_datetime) next_change_dt
    from mytable t
) t
group by ap_work_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68c53b5947a7e1d0325056d2ecf0e6f8)**:

```
ap_work_id | assigned_hrs | in_progress_hrs | rejected_hrs | hold_hrs | closed_hrs
---------: | -----------: | --------------: | -----------: | -------: | ---------:
   1060565 |           18 |               6 |            3 |       15 |       null
```

Results are a bit different than what you showed (and I had to fix the date on the row that has status Assigned, that was not consistent with the rest of the data), but I think these are actually correct for your sample data.

Comment: Really You are genius... Awesome. Just you get simply and also it is easy to understand even for leymann and that too with real example. Thanks a lot dude...

Comment: It is showing some warning like "you should have 25 reputations for vote" if i tried to vote up.